# How to hide unwanted relationships between nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new in Neo4j and I have a weird requirement.

I have some node

```
CREATE (a:node {title:1})
CREATE (b:node {title:2})
CREATE (c:node {title:3})
CREATE (d:node {title:4})
```

and multiple relationships between them:

```
CREATE (a)-[:RELATES{jump:[1]}]->(b)
CREATE (b)-[:RELATES{jump:[1]}]->(c)
CREATE (c)-[:RELATES{jump:[1]}]->(d)
CREATE (a)-[:RELATES{jump:[2]}]->(c)
CREATE (c)-[:RELATES{jump:[2]}]->(d)
CREATE (d)-[:RELATES{jump:[1]}]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[:RELATES{jump:[3]}]->(d)
CREATE (d)-[:RELATES{jump:[3]}]->(c)
CREATE (c)-[:RELATES{jump:[3]}]->(b)
```

The graph and the relationship are shown here:
[image]

I want to check the graph such that only those relationships should be visible which I'm interested in. 
Now when I do something like this: `MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) WHERE 1 IN r.jump RETURN a,b`

I get the something like:

[image]

Is there a way where I can hide(not delete) the not relevant relationships while displaying the graph? May be something like this(edited on Image tool):

[image]

PS: Let Grey be white.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default the Neo4j Browser uses an "Auto-Complete" feature to show **all** relationships that exist between nodes in the visualization. You can change this by toggling the "Auto-Complete" button in the Neo4j browser:

[image]

This will exclude any relationships not explicitly returned in the Cypher query from the visualization.

Note that you will need to explicitly return the relationships you are interested in. So your query becomes:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b) 
WHERE 1 IN r.jump 
RETURN a,r,b
```

Answer (score 37):

In neo4j 3.2.1 this feature has been relocated to the bottom left corner, under the gear icon: "Connect result nodes" (checked by default, thus returning all relationships between nodes included in the result).

[image: uncheck the box]

Comment: thank you, it works! but i have a question, how do i "explicitly" ask for a relationship to be shown? i have a case where i only wanna see 1 relationship but it gives me all of them. ex: MATCH (p:Person)-[:belong]->(o:Organisation) RETURN p,o

Comment: EDIT: found it, had to up the "Initial Node Display" option or it wouldn't show for some reason.