# Neo4j Cypher Query Not Filtering on Edge Label

Tags: cypher, matching

I've got a simple network of a small number of actors that have directed relations which change over time through an iterative process.  For example, there may be an edge between actors 'XJ' and 'LK' for `Turn=0`, but then for `Turn=1`, 'XJ' may be related to 'XS'.  The iteration number `Turn` is a label on the edges.  I'm trying to draw the graph of all relationships by iteration, and so query:

```
match p=()-[b {Turn:0}]->() return p;
```

If I look at the Rows "tab", it is returning the filtered rows, but when I view the graph "Tab", neo4j draws the entire graph.  How can I get neo4j to draw the graph filtered by the label as instructed in the `match`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603618/how-to-hide-unwanted-relationships-between-nodes-in-neo4j/37603703#37603703

Comment: Thanks Will.  That was it.