# Neo4j displays all relationships but I want only 1 specif relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am querying a database and I want to display only a certain relationship but I get from neo4j all the relationships.
 [image]

This is my code:

```
MATCH (p1:Person {name:'John Snow'})-[r:LOVES]-> (p2:Person {name:'Daenerys Targaryen'})
 return p1,p2,r
```

*I want to show only:* (Jon Snow) -[Loves]-> (Deanerys Targaryen)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cypher query gives unnecessary relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759688/cypher-query-gives-unnecessary-relationships)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide unwanted relationships between nodes in Neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603618/how-to-hide-unwanted-relationships-between-nodes-in-neo4j)

Answer (score 1):

Your query return as you expected.

Open the Table/Text tab, you will see that only matching relationship is returned.

I guess the GUI client just try to smart to visualize all relationships for you.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off autocomplete option on you Neo4j Browser.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv76F.png)